# Castle Windsor - How to map Named instance in constructor injection

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

maybe this is easy, but searching it on the internet already give me a head ache

here is the problem:

```
interface IValidator
{
    void Validate(object obj);
}

public class ValidatorA : IValidator
{
    public void Validate(object obj) { }
}

public class ValidatorB : IValidator
{
    public void Validate(object obj) { }
}


interface IClassA { }
interface IClassB { }

public class MyBaseClass
{
    protected IValidator validator;

    public void Validate()
    {
        validator.Validate(this);
    }
}

public class ClassA : MyBaseClass, IClassA
{
    //problem: validator should ValidatorA
    public ClassA(IValidator validator) { }
}

public class ClassB : MyBaseClass, IClassB
{
    //problem: validator should ValidatorB
    public ClassB(IValidator validator) { }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public OtherClass(IClassA a, IClassB b) { }
}


//on Main
var oc = container.Resolve<OtherClass>();
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**

I registered `ValidatorA` and `ValidatorB` with `Named`, now the problem how Castle Windsor can inject those validator properly to the `ClassA` and `ClassB`, is there a way to do that? or is there any better solution?

if there is someone think my class design is wrong please, i open for any advice. So far i think it correct. Yes, validator have specific configuration for specific Class. but there are reasons it is abstracted:

1. Validator is a complex object, sometime should connect to database, so I MUST pass interface instead of implementation to constructor for unit testing reason.
2. No way to use different interface for any of Validator, because the only method that i used is `Validate`
3. I think `MyBaseClass.Validate()` a common **template method** pattern isn't it?

Comment: Your description of problem is to abstract.

Comment: If ClassA requires specific implementation of IValidator, then the design is wrong, as the interface provides no useful abstraction.

Comment: @Jacek Grogon, no i only need the `Validate` method, actually there is a baseclass of ClassA and ClassB which is call the `Validate` method. but i don't write it here just to hide complexity.

Comment: updated the code, so the only think i really need is the `Validate` method

Comment: Create an interface for ClassA and ClassB something like IClassAValidator that inherits from IValidator and adds nothing more. Then get the validators to implement the specific interface. ClassA can then have IClassAValidator injected into it and pass the IValidator to MyBaseClass.

Comment: @JackHughes: sorry don't properly read your answer, yes that was my thought.. thank you, but still looking for the exact answer.. is it really impossible to do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without going into the details of your chosen architecture just focusing on the Windsor container configuration:

If you have registered multiple named implementation to a given interface (`IValidator`), you can specify  which one do you want to use when registering the consumer classes (`ClassA`, `ClassB`) with using `ServiceOverrides`:

The following container configuration providers an `OtherClass` with `ClassA` instance with a `ValidatorA` and `ClassB` instance with a `ValidatorB`:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(Component.For<IClassA>().ImplementedBy<ClassA>()
    .DependsOn(ServiceOverride.ForKey<IValidator>().Eq("ValidatorA")));
container.Register(Component.For<IClassB>().ImplementedBy<ClassB>()
    .DependsOn(ServiceOverride.ForKey<IValidator>().Eq("ValidatorB")));

container.Register(Component.For<IValidator>().ImplementedBy<ValidatorA>()
    .Named("ValidatorA"));
container.Register(Component.For<IValidator>().ImplementedBy<ValidatorB>()
    .Named("ValidatorB"));

container.Register(Component.For<OtherClass>().ImplementedBy<OtherClass>());

var oc = container.Resolve<OtherClass>();
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're trying to put tight couples (`ClassA` with `ValidatorA`, `ClassB` with `ValidatorB`) as independent types into a common container. This is pointless. If you must rely on tight coupling like this, forget dependency injection in this regard and just hard-reference the types.

This would make more sense if you could implement a common validator for all classes. For instance, make the classes responsible for providing validation rules, and let `Validator`
just enforce the rules. Or perhaps just include the whole validation inside your classes, which is probably the most sensible scenario here.

`MyBaseClass.Validate()` look like inversion of control, but not like a template method.

Comment: thanks for the response, yes the class was thight couple, but the process is repetitive, actually there are tasks in `MyBaseClass.Validate()`: 1. Get the erros from `validator.Validate(this)`, 2. Dispatch the `DataErrorEvent` 3. Change the `HasError` property,(Thats why I call it tempalte method) all those task should done in assynchron way. it would be a bad idea to do it in every ClassA and ClassB right?

Comment: If so then ``Validate()`` is indeed template method. Still, why not put the ingredient method, say ``ValidateCore()`` in ``ClassA`` and not in ``ValidatorA``? If it's repetitive, then put it in ``MyBaseClass``. Extracting the ``Validator`` class adds more complexity and hinders clarity.

Comment: if im not msitaken, you mean instantiate the `ValidatorA` inside `ClassA` and make new method `ValidateCore` then call `ValidateCore` from `MyBaseClass.Validate()` right?. i think i can't do that because it will impossible to do unit test where `ValidatorA` or `ValidatorB` in any cases should connect to database.

Comment: I mean remove Validator* and put that logic in Class*.ValidateCore() and call it in MyBaseClass.Validate(). What exactly are you unit testing? Why is ValidatorA connecting to a database? Give more context.

Comment: ClassA or ClassB should only contains logic of the view (state of button, selectedIndex of combobox etc) it is really required to test its logic outside the database call, in some case Validator connect to database to get information, is there some property match specific condition of data or not? if i remove Validator and do the validation inside it so my unit testing should connect to database and i think it is not a good idea, do you think I over used the validator class? btw.. once again thank you, i really appreciate your time to try to solve my problem

Comment: The architecture seems somewhat odd, with DB validation bound directly to view. To cut further discussions about it, I recommend just going with the approach suggested by Jack Hughes in comments. There is no repetition in that.