# Proper way of injecting different set of componenets based on some flag in Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am working with the legacy application. In my spear time, I want to make some clean up with components initialization and move most of them to Windsor (which is our company DI framework of choice).

Unfortunately, in old days, some one decided to use Windsor via XML configuration files, which is really complicating things...

Ok, straight to the problem. I want to inject a different set of implementation depending on some flag or root component implementation, for example, let's say I have FlowA and FlowB and I want to have this hierarchy injected:

**FlowA:**

- SomeFactoryA : IFactoryComponenet
- SomeService1A : IService1
- SomeService2 : IService2
- SomeService3 : IService3

**FlowB:**

- SomeFactoryB : IFactoryComponenet
- SomeService1B : IService1
- SomeService2 : IService2
- SomeService3 : IService3

Basically, some of the components have a single implementation, some have different. I have always a few implementations of services, some are for legacy mode, some for a new flow, some for other special variants of the flow.

The only thing which came to my mind it to wrap all this staff in the factory, but then I have a feeling that this is just removing DI framework in some way and I am loosing a flexibility of individual components changes.

Is there any way to instruct Windsor to recognize some parameter and the inject different implementations? Or I am misusing the DI here. If the latter, any suggestions how to properly deal with this kind of requirements apart and old school switch (eventually hidden behind factory)

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: As long as you can mock your factories I dont see any problem with this approach.

Comment: Side note: working on on your employer's product **in your spare time** is a **bad idea**.

Comment: MarioDS, maybe I wasn't precise here. It is like a best effort driven clean up exercise. It is not unofficial thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [Named Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11331681/3351148)

You can try something like

FlowA and FlowB implement IWorkflow

```
container.Register(Component.For<IWorkflow>().ImplementedBy<FlowA>()
    .DependsOn(ServiceOverride.ForKey<IService1>().Eq("SomeService1A")));

container.Register(Component.For<IService1>().ImplementedBy<SomeService1A>()
    .Named("SomeService1A"));
```

With this you enforce a specific dependency SomeService1A for FlowA.
Do the same for all workflow specific dependencies (eg. IFactoryComponenet)